# RavenDb faceted search with filtered out facet ranges included

Tags: ravendb, faceted-search

I want to ask if there is a way in RavenDb to execute a faceted search but get also the facets which were filtered out.

Example:

Let's have a `Car` entity with properties `Color : string` and `Status : enum(New,Used)`.

When I search for `Red` cars I would also like to get counts in all other colors. Similarly if I search for `Used` cars I want to see also count of new cars.

If I have everything unchecked:

```
UI
Color:  [ ] Red (5)   [ ] Blue (7) [ ] White (15)
Status: [ ] Used (20) [ ] New (7)

C#
session.Query<Car, Cars_Index>().ToFacets("facets/Cars");
```

I get the proper result.

But once I filter for both `Color` and `Status` I get very limited results:

```
UI
Color:  [x] Red (3)
Status: [x] Used (3)

C#
session.Query<Car, Cars_Index>()
    .Where(a => a.Status == CarStatus.Used)
    .Where(a => a.Color == "Red")
    .ToFacets("facets/Cars");

Response (JSON):
{ "Color": [ { "Range": "Red", "Count": 3 } ], "Status" : [ { "Range": "Used", "Count": 3 } ] }
```

What I do currently I issue a separate query for each facet:

```
var colorFacet = session.Query<Car, Cars_Index>()
    .Where(a => a.Status == CarStatus.Used)
    .ToFacets("facets/Cars");


var statusFacet = session.Query<Car, Cars_Index>()
    .Where(a => a.Color == "Red")
    .ToFacets("facets/Cars");
```

What I would like to achieve:

```
UI
Color:  [x] Red (3)  [ ] Blue (4) [ ] White (12)
Status: [x] Used (3) [ ] New (7)
```

So get the number of Red Used cars, Blue Used cars, White used cars and User red cars and New red cars. So the user has an immediate feedback what will happen when he clicks a checkbox.

Which with growing number and variability of facets becomes unmanageable. Is there a way how to set it up, that it can be executed in one request/query.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That isn't how facets are working with RavenDB (or in general, for that matter).
You look at facets based on your *current* query, not intersection of all the facets.

Comment: Well, sorry to hear that. But I'm afraid that's a feature of Lucene and not RavenDB, so there not even a change of having this as a RavenDB feature request